# Custom thumbnail design css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

Relatively new in web design. Maybe this is trivial but I see people help each other here, so I seek help in achieving this thumbnail design (on my bootstrap site):

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Please share code what you have tried so far.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please read the following to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following design has two divs. There is a main division with another div in it, and for the curve corners only at top-left and top right you can use this code:

```
.maindiv {
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}
```

for the whole division design in HTML, You can use:

```
<div class="maindiv">
 <!-- Image Here -->
 <div class="foo">
  <!-- Content Here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you very much! :)